# show linebreak characters with django

Tags: django, django-templates, escaping

how i can display the linebreaks in django ?
exemple:
`my_variable = 'hello world\r\n`
I would like to have in my html page the exact value of **my_variable**. I don't want the interpretation of linebreaks

Comment: What do expect to have in `template`? you just want to display it as it is `'hello world\r\n`

Comment: yes. I want to display as it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double escaping:

```
my_variable = 'Hello, World!\\r\\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the **double escaping(\\r\\n)** of *@Sergey Miletskiy*'s answer and adding the following lines in my template.

`{% autoescape off %}
    {{ my_variable }}
 {% endautoescape %}`